# How would something that counts up in a specific base work in python?

Tags: python, decoding

So, I'm making python code to basically brute force encryption (because why not) but the code I have is really inefficient Basically I have a script that loops over a list with letters/numbers in it, and it just has a bunch of for loops that increment each but one, and once that one ends, it increments the next one and so on. It does work right now, but like I said, its super inefficient. The current code I have so far is this (this one is for SHA-512):

```py
def bruteForceDecryptSHALength3(encrypted, characters):
    # For 1-3 letter words
    decrypt = ""
    for c1 in characters:
        decrypt = c1
        if hashlib.sha512(decrypt.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() == encrypted:
            return decrypt
        for c2 in characters:
            decrypt = c1 + c2
            if hashlib.sha512(decrypt.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() == encrypted:
                return decrypt
            for c3 in characters:
                decrypt = c1 + c2 + c3
                if hashlib.sha512(decrypt.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() == encrypted:
                    return decrypt
```

I just want to know a way to use *less* for loops, that gives the same result, so that I have a more efficient way of brute forcing (which is still really really inefficient)

Comment: Please post the code you have so far for reference.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just perform the addition of 1 to a list that contains the individual digits of the number.

```py
def addOne(digits):
  index = 0
  carry = 1
  while carry == 1:
    index -= 1
    sum = digits[index] + carry
    digits[index] = sum & 0x1
    carry = sum >> 1

digits = [0] * 10
for _ in range(15):
  addOne(digits)
  print(''.join(map(str,digits)))
```

---

Based on your edit of the question it is more clear what you want.

You want to enumerate the Cartesian Product of N collections of characters.

```py
import hashlib
from itertools import product

def bruteForceDecryptSHALengthN(encrypted, characters, N=3):
  for charCount in range(1, N+1):
    for decryptTpl in product(characters, repeat=charCount):
      decrypt = ''.join(decryptTpl)
      if hashlib.sha512(decrypt.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() == encrypted:
          return decrypt
```

Comment: I'm impressed that you were able to understand the problem. May I ask what it is?

Comment: @InSync I read the title `counts up like binary but with a list`, I just simulate the full adders used in a CPU

Comment: I'm afraid that I failed to see the link between "*counts up like binary*" and "*full adders used in a CPU*". Could you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @InSync If you have a decimal number, digits are 0..9, how do you add 1 to the number? In a binary number you only have digits 0..1, `>>1` is equivalent with `/2` but faster, at least in a CPU, in Python the overhead is big because behind the scenes an integer is using base 2^31